# Eclipse- new empty branch creation

Tags: eclipse, git, user-interface

How can I create new EMPTY branch in Eclipse using GUI?
Is there any way to do that?
I know, that using console is it possible to use something called "orphan" branch. But I can't find how to do it using Eclipse GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JGit only got the `checkout --orphan` earlier this year ([January 2014](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/pull/11), [gerrit change](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/20095/), [commit 2f425cf](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/commit/2f425cf30c79917a93eeeac0ee3fcfc7af77d203)).

It uses ([`org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CheckoutCommandTest.java#L375-L378`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/2f425cf30c79917a93eeeac0ee3fcfc7af77d203/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CheckoutCommandTest.java#L375-L378))

```
private CheckoutCommand newOrphanBranchCommand() {
  return git.checkout().setOrphan(true)
    .setName("orphanbranch");
}
```

But nowhere [in eclipse/egit code](https://github.com/eclipse/egit) do you find a `setOrphan()` call.

That means that feature hasn't yet been integrated in EGit.